# Word 2010 superscript shortcut stopped working

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-word, keyboard-shortcuts, microsoft-word-2010

I'm running Word 2010 on Windows 8, and as of a couple days ago, the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>+</kbd> shortcut no longer does anything (whereas it used to apply superscript formatting). Oddly, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>=</kbd> still makes subscripts.

No major system changes, to the best of my knowledge, and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>+</kbd> still appears in Customize Ribbon > Customize Keyboard > Commands > Superscript.

This is driving me nuts - does anyone have any suggestions on how to fix this?

Comment: Spontaneously resolved, much to my relief/puzzlement, so never mind!