# German Word 2010 with English UI and US English Keyboard – some hotkeys do not work

Tags: windows-7, keyboard-shortcuts, microsoft-word-2010, keyboard-layout, hotkeys

## System

In my office I am working at a computer with a **German version of Windows 7** and a **German Office 2010** suite.

The **Windows system language** has been changed to **English**. The Office applications have the same language as Windows.

We have **German keyboards** but I changed the **keyboard language to U.S. English**. This also works fine.

## Standard Shortcuts

These work fine:

- <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> for bold
- <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> for find
- <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> for back (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd> on the German real keyboard)
- <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> for italic word fine.

## Shortcuts with the "Shift" key do not work properly

- **Show/Hide** has <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>(</kbd> according to the "Customize Keyboard" window. Thus, I should type <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>9</kbd> to get <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>(</kbd>.
- However, I have to type <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>8</kbd> which is <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>*</kbd> on the English keyboard but would be <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>(</kbd> on a German keyboard.

## Subscript and Superscript

- Typing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>=</kbd> does nothing
- <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd> does subscript (but it should do superscript)
- The correct keys are assigned in Word configuration.

Now I set the hot keys manually.

- Typing <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>=</kbd> for subscript works fine.
- Typing <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>=</kbd> for superscript shows <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>*</kbd> as the assigned hotkey (which is <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>8</kbd>).

Back in Word: I type <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>8</kbd> which does "Show/Hide". I type <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>=</kbd> which does superscript.

Opening the customize keyboard window again shows the assignment of
<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>*</kbd> for superscript as before.

## Summary

<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>=</kbd> is printed as <kbd>+</kbd> when typed in a MS Word document. But <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>=</kbd> is not interpreted as <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>+</kbd> but as <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>*</kbd>.

The same states for <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>8</kbd> which is printed as <kbd>*</kbd> but in combination with <kbd>CTRL</kbd> recognized as <kbd>(</kbd>.

The problem does not arise at our Terminal Server which runs Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise.

It might be related to [Word 2010 superscript shortcut stopped working](https://superuser.com/questions/772976/word-2010-superscript-shortcut-stopped-working).

**Question:** Why does MS Word behave in this way? How can this issue be solved?

---

**edit:**

Interestingly, the shortcuts <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>=</kbd> and <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>=</kbd> work fine in MS Powerpoint 2010 on the same machine.

I tried the same on fresh installed Windows 7 and the problem is reproducible (German Windows, change System Language, change Keyboard Settings to U.S. English):

- **MS Word:** hotkeys <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>=</kbd> and <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>=</kbd> **do not work**
- **MS Powerpoint:** hotkeys <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>=</kbd> and <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>=</kbd> **do work**

Comment: Did you take into account the difference in US keyboard layout versus the German / European keyboard layout?

Comment: On the US keyboard the "="/"+" key is left of backspace. On the German keyboard the "´"/"`" key is left of backspace. If I type that key (left of backspace) I get "=" and if I type it with "Shift" I get "+" as it should be on the US keyboard. Was that your question? The other keys work as well as they should work on an US keyboard.

Comment: It's not very clear what your real question is.

Comment: I added a summary and modified the question. Is it clear now?

Comment: Have you found any solution for this? It completely does not work on my German keyboard.

Comment: Not really. Do you have the same setup? I ended up with assuming that the Windows language packs are differently interpreted by MS Powerpoint and MS Word. Maybe some "global language" shortcuts are overwritten by some local MS Word keyboard-language-specific shortcuts ... . But, if you have the same problem, I am quite happy that their is someone else having the same problem ;-) . My personal solution was: Switching back to a German-language MS Windows with American English Keyboard layout.